# mySQL combining multiple queries

Tags: php, sql

I'm running some sql code from my PHP site/game to find the players friends and enemies online. Both are pulling data from the same tables.

```
// friends online
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts c 
    INNER JOIN online o ON o.playerID = c.playerID 
    WHERE c.myID=".$id." AND c.type='friends'

// enemies online
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contacts c 
    INNER JOIN online o ON o.playerID = c.playerID 
    WHERE c.myID=".$id." AND c.type='enemies'
```

Is there a way to combine these together and get two counts at the end? Would that be faster?

Comment: SQL queries traditionally start with `SELECT`.  And, with your rep, you should know to tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will yield the type and the count:

```
type  count
friends  0
enemies   2


select c.type, COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM contacts c 
    INNER JOIN online o ON o.playerID = c.playerID 
    WHERE c.myID=".$id." AND c.type in ('friends','enemies')
group by c.type;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation.  The general form is:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c.type = 'friends' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_friends,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.type = 'enemies' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_enemies       
FROM contacts c INNER JOIN
     online o 
     ON o.playerID = c.playerID 
WHERE c.myID = ".$id.";
```

Yes, this is faster than two queries.  If you have lots of types, you can add `AND type in ('friends', 'enemies')`.

Your query is not using the `online` table, unless it is being used for filtering.  If this is not necessary, then remove it from the query.